# What is the deflective efficiency of glass?

Tags: electrons, air, plasma-physics, ions

If I have ions, electrons, and gas particles bouncing off of glass, how much energy will the particles retain? what % of the energy will be be retained what % lost, the particles I am referring to are particles of arc plasma, not neccessary at full density.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflection_(physics)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_arc

Comment: To the extent that glass is an insulator, it must be impervious to charged particles such as electrons and ions.

Answer (score 0):

Glass is an excellent insulator as shown in this picture. The gas inside is ionized to allow electricity to easily travel through the space.

[image]

Glass is not impervious to electromagnetic charge shown below. Any moving electrons makes an electromagnetic charge.

[image]

In the last picture shows if the voltage is high enough it will pass through the glass.

[image]